# Which is which in XxY specifications (i.e. 5x5, 3x5, etc.)?

Tags: workout-routines, programs, sets

When specifying sets and reps like 5x5, 3x5, (in general, XxY), which is which?

It seems like it usually means "X sets of Y reps." but on some forums I see logs that seem to indicate that either they are (a) doing dozens of 1 rep sets (which might be valid) or (b) they are using the notation in the other order (i.e. "X reps done Y times").

Is there a "traditional" way of reading/writing these?

Comment: and so we have one answer for each of my alternatives. Figures. ;)

Comment: In most circles I've read it (as far as teaching goes) its sets x reps.  The only people whom I've seen refer to it in an opposite manner would be folks from Great Briton.  They've also been known to call a 4x5 camera a 5x4--so it's more of a localization issue.  Kind of like the way Germans swap the meaning of commas and periods when writing numbers.

Comment: [It's not just Germans who write numbers the *normal* way](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/DecimalSeparator.svg) ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Universe is an Uncaring Void

I've seen sources say "3x5" (three sets of five) but denote their workouts as 100x5x3 (100 pounds, 5 reps, 3 sets). I've also seen sources say "3x5" and write 3x5 and mean three sets of five in both cases. There is no clear answer to your question. YxZ is fundamentally ambiguous.

### Show Your Units

In physics, I was taught to never leave the units ambiguous in our calculations. "5" means nothing; "5 Newtons" means something. I think that advice applies here too. We have competing standards each trying to be the One True Answer. Our only reasonable course of action is to somehow indicate that 3x5 *in this case* means three sets of five rather than five sets of three.

I independently developed two methods of showing my units: marking my sets as I complete them, and putting commas between "x reps" to show different sets.

### The Ticking-Off-Sets Method

I do this haphazardly in my own training notes, either simply remembering, or ticking off sets as I complete them:

> Front squat: 45x5, 95x5, 145x5, 195x5x3  '''

This says I warmed up my front squat with a set of five each at 45, 95, and 145 pounds  before my work sets. The three tick marks at the end show that I completed three work sets, telling me-six-months-from-now that I meant three sets of five. I certainly don't think this method is optimal.

### The Comma Method

Another method I use refuses to write down the number of sets at all, but instead demarcates sets with commas, like so:

> Front squat: (45,95,145)x5, 195 x5,x5,x5

This says the same thing as above--three warm-up sets, then three work sets. I think this is perhaps my most unambiguous and concise notation, making it the best.

It has a drawback that is also a benefit: it accounts for failures. This is good, because it minimizes scratching out "3x5" when I fail at the last set. It's bad, because it reduces the consequences and certainty of completing the sets as planned.

Answer (score 16):

3x5 is 3 sets of 5 reps - it follows the same order as when you write or say it.

Two examples from two well known strength coaches & programs:

[Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Texas_Method):

> Reduce the volume on Monday. Sometimes
>   the Monday’s workout is too stressful.
>   You need more time to recover.
>
> You can try:
>
> 1. Dropping a work set or two (**5x5 becomes 4x5 or 3x5**)

Or [T Nation](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance/how_to_build_pure_strength):

> Each training cycle lasts four weeks,
>   with these set-rep goals for each
>   major lift:
>
> - Week 1: 3 x **5**
> - Week 2: 3 x **3**
> - Week 3: 3 x **5, 3, 1**
> - Week 4: deloading
>
> (...)
>
> Exercise 1)
>   Standing shoulder press:  3 sets of:
>
> - Week 1 - **5 reps**
> - Week 2 - **3 reps**
> - Week 3 - **5/3/1 reps**
> - Week 4 - **5 reps**

Comment: I like this because it goes from most significant to least significant. It has the same appeal as the international date format of yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the word is.

```
5 x 10 pushups
5 x 15 situps
5 x 50 jumping jacks
```

Looks a lot nicer than

```
10 pushups x 5
15 situps x 5
50 jumping jacks x 5
```

The prettier way to write it would be the first option.